# Determine when a remote system is rebooted

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# program that calls a batch file that reboots the a remote system to another partition.  Is there a way to know when the system is done rebooting?  I would like to know when I can access the remote system once it is rebooted.

Comment: What do plan to perform next when the reboot is done ?

Comment: Once the reboot is done, I plan on using "image for windows" to install a base image, and then I will reboot back to the partition I started on.

Answer (score 6):

I would ping it to determine when it's back online. There's a [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) built right into .net.

Comment: However I would put a timeout in this. Say after two minutes of pinging you give up and raise an alert or throw an error. Could be dangerous to ping away for ever.

Answer (score 4):

When system A tells system B to reboot, maybe it could supply its ip address (or other contact info), and then in system Bs startup process it could read the file with the contact info and call back to system A.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options...

You can try to connect to a network service on the other system, ie: use Ping as [suggested by Jon B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848622/determine-when-a-remote-system-is-rebooted/848648#848648).

However, if the system is one under your control, you have other options.  You could setup a scheduled task (or install a service) to start on boot, and have the other system notify you when it is online.  This would prevent you from needing to ping repeatedly.

Comment: I am trying to set up a test environment with a new image.  Once the system is set up, I am going to try and run automated tests on it.  So, I may not have control of the remote system while I am setting it up.  The ping option should work.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, if it's going to be a fresh image, ping is probably your best option.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had used this site before I spent all day Saturday trying to figure this out.  Thanks for the help!!  Below is what I ended up doing.  This code will ping a computer and determine when it is back online.  The next step will be to determine if I can open a network connection to the remote desktop port as suggested earlier.  Feel free to make any comments on the code.

Note:  Here are the added using statements:

using System.Net;                   // added
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;// added
using System.ComponentModel;        // added
using System.Threading;             // added

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string systemName = "172.30.11.148";      // Name of system beign pinged.  System name used instead of ip due to DHCP 

        Ping pingSender = new Ping();                       // Creates new ping object.  
        string data = "datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata";   // buffer of 32 bytes of data to transmit.
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);      // buffer containing data.

        int pingTimeout = 120;          // Timeout in ms sent into pingSender.
        int maxWaitTimeout = 60;        // Maximum time to wait for system to reboot.
        int counter = 1;                // Used in while statement
        bool connectStatus = false;     // State of system connection.

        Console.WriteLine("Wait for reboot to start before trying to establish connection.");
        //Thread.Sleep(30000);            // Waits 30 seconds at start of reboot to allow network to close.
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        try
        {
            // Performs a ping on the system.  If the system is available, while loop is exited and program
            // continues.  If the system is not available, program waits approximately 1 second and then
            // pings the system again.
            while (counter < maxWaitTimeout)
            {
                // Pings the system with 32 byts of data and waits for timeout
                Console.WriteLine("Connection attempt #: " + counter + " of " + maxWaitTimeout);
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(systemName, pingTimeout, buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Status of ping to: {0} - {1}", systemName, reply.Status);

                if (reply.Status.ToString() == "Success")
                {
                    connectStatus = true;                     
                    Console.WriteLine("\nRoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
                    Console.WriteLine("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(880);
                counter += 1;                  
            } // end while loop

            if (connectStatus == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nAble to establish connection to: {0}", systemName);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUnable to establish network connection using ping to: {0}", systemName);
            }
        } // end try

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();     // Pause console

    } // end main
```